# Spending money ideas?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

I amassed solid amount of money but I don't have a clue what to do with it other than buying new armor and weapons. Are there any other "money sink" mechanics in Dragon Age: Inquisition?

Answer (score 5):

You can go to the Val Royeaux furniture store and buy some customization options for Skyhold. Or you can buy Influence from Faris (in Skyhold) in case you want something that actually affects gameplay. Close to Faris are the horse stables, where you can buy more mounts as well.

Comment: Thanks, are you sure that this is all options? There are not much to do...

Comment: There's probably some more I haven't listed.

Comment: Thanks, Yuuki, I wasn't aware about money for influence.